# Odata multiple expand

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata

I´m trying to expand an object to the 3rd level in Odata but its not working. I read the documentation and some question in the web but i cant find the solution.

I´m trying to execute this:

```
http://localhost:8081/odata/drivers?$skip=0&$top=10&$count=true&$expand=driversTrips($expand=trip($expand=tripsDestinations))&$filter=IsActive eq true and IsOnline eq true&$orderBy=Id asc
```

I get my object "drivers" with "driversTrips", and "driversTrips" with "trip". I have all the simply propperties like id, status, origin, time in "trip" but the "tripsDestinations" array is not appearing.

Also I have tried the following url, to check if I have an error in my relations. In the response I get the "trip" with array "tripsDestinations" filled.

```
http://localhost:8081/odata/trips?$skip=0&$top=10&$count=true&$expand=tripsDestinations&$filter=IsActive eq true and tripStatusId eq 1&$orderBy=Id asc
```

I have configured the GET method in my API with this parameter "MaxExpansionDepth = 0" and still not working.

Any suggestion?
Thanks Joni